# Why the JSTL format Number pattern #00.00 doesn't show $0.00 but shows $1,356.00?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Following is the piece of code used in JSP

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${A.B}" pattern="$#,###.00" />
```

The data type from Java server side is BigDecimal. If the value is non-zero, it is getting shown correctly. But only if it is 0.00, it is displaying as `$.00`

Why is that?
How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `0` for the first digit instead of `#` to force the first digit:

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${A.B}" pattern="$#,##0.00" />
```

Or you can use the `currency` formatter:

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${A.B}" type="currency" />
```

Comment: But if I use 0 for the first digit instead of # and if the actual value for first digit is non-zero (say $1.00), will it work?

Comment: @user3705478 Does it work for the decimal digits? Why don't you try? :)